# CSS hover animation does curve

Tags: html, css

I made an animation for my header. I used translateY on an  element inside a  element. And I changed the border color of the  element. It looks like the text is makeing a little ) movement. It makes a curve. Does anyone know how to fix that? [My CodePen Code](https://codepen.io/rangobro/pen/JjRMoZy?editors=1100)

```
.header .desktop-nav nav .norm_anker:hover p {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .norm_anker:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #004892;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header .desktop-nav {
  background-color: #00000000;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}


/*
 * dropdown_menu
 */

.header .desktop-nav nav .dropdown_menu {
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  display: none;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .dropdown_menu .dropdown_button {
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  padding-top: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0000;
  border-color: #004892;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0) all 0.17s;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .dropdown_menu .dropdown_button p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0) all 0.18s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .dropdown_menu .dropdown_content {
  background-color: #004892;
  position: absolute;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s all;
  height: 92px;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .dropdown_menu .dropdown_content .dropdown_anker_container {
  display: none;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .dropdown_menu .dropdown_content .dropdown_anker_container .dropdown_anker {
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  padding-top: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0000;
  border-color: #004892;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0) all 0.17s;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .dropdown_menu .dropdown_content .dropdown_anker_container .dropdown_anker p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0) all 0.18s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .dropdown_menu .dropdown_content .dropdown_anker_container .dropdown_anker:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .dropdown_menu .dropdown_content .dropdown_anker_container .dropdown_anker:hover p {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}


/*
 * Normal Nav Bar
 */

.header .desktop-nav nav .norm_anker {
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  padding-top: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0000;
  border-color: #004892;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0) all 0.17s;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .norm_anker p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0) all 0.18s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .norm_anker:hover p {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .norm_anker:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
}

.content {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="desktop-nav">
    <nav>
      <!-- Desktop Nav Links -->
      <a class="norm_anker anker_1" href="/">
        <p>Startseite</p>
      </a>
      <a class="norm_anker anker_2" href="/classes">
        <p>Unterricht</p>
      </a>
      <a class="norm_anker anker_3" href="/vehicles">
        <p>Fahrzeuge</p>
      </a>
      <a class="norm_anker anker_4" href="/about">
        <p>Über uns</p>
      </a>
      <section class="dropdown_menu">
        <a class="dropdown_button" data-status="close" href="javascript:dropdownChooseAction();">
          <p>Mehr</p>
        </a>

        <div style="height: 0px; padding: 0 10px;" class="dropdown_content">
          <section class="dropdown_anker_container dropdown_anker_container_1">
            <a class="dropdown_anker_1 dropdown_anker" href="/about">
              <p>Über uns</p>
            </a>
          </section>
          <section class="dropdown_anker_container dropdown_anker_container_2">
            <a class="dropdown_anker_2 dropdown_anker" href="/blocklessons">
              <p>Blockunterricht</p>
            </a>
          </section>
          <section class="dropdown_anker_container dropdown_anker_container_3">
            <a class="dropdown_anker_3 dropdown_anker" href="/driverscam">
              <p>Driverscam</p>
            </a>
          </section>
        </div>
      </section>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am confused as to where you see "a little ) movement"... Can you be more specific?

Comment: The text doesnt only go up, it looks like it makes a little kurve, like a round bracket )

Comment: I see... that happens only in Chrome and I'm using Firefox. Let me see with the old Chrome

Comment: In my opinion its the same in firefox. At least with the "Über Uns"

Comment: It doesn't happen in Firefox on Unix... anyway the reason for this is your `transition: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0) all 0.18s;` ... change that to `transition: ease all 0.18s;` and it'll work smoother

Comment: I've added a snippet. I can see the curve you mean when using Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `display: inline-block` on the anchors and adding `display: flex` to the nav:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #004892;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header .desktop-nav {
  background-color: #00000000;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

/*
 * Normal Nav Bar
 */

.header .desktop-nav nav .norm_anker {
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  padding-top: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0000;
  border-color: #004892;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: ease all 0.18s;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .norm_anker p {
  margin: 0;
  transition: ease all 0.18s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .norm_anker:hover p {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

.header .desktop-nav nav .norm_anker:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="desktop-nav">
    <nav>
      <!-- Desktop Nav Links -->
      <a class="norm_anker anker_1" href="/">
        <p>Startseite</p>
      </a>
      <a class="norm_anker anker_2" href="/classes">
        <p>Unterricht</p>
      </a>
      <a class="norm_anker anker_3" href="/vehicles">
        <p>Fahrzeuge</p>
      </a>
      <a class="norm_anker anker_4" href="/about">
        <p>Über uns</p>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesnt work 100%. It looks still kinda weird